# Gboard Arabic keyboard layout with extra-alphabetic diacritics

Tags: keyboard, gboard, text-layout

I was wondering whether it would be a good idea for the implementers of gboard Arabic keyboard to include a keyboard layout, perhaps for adult and kid learners, that included the ability to insert all the diacritics, including the ones that are not normally written (the fatah (a and e sound), kesra (i sound), dumma (o u sound), shadda (doubling of consonants), sukun (small circle indicating no vowel sound), alif with small mim above (mim is for muting, I think), and tilde above alif (alif madda, I think for lengthening).

I was wondering whether it would be a good idea in Gboard to have a keyboard that allowed you to input these diacritics (extra alphabetic diacritics and all).

Can someone please point me to where I could find such a keyboard in Gboard?

The fatah, kesra, dumma, and shadda, are not usually written down, but can be used by someone for studying (/ remembering where they go).

Perhaps a special button could be added, allowing the user to add the diacritics, where it made sense.

Or, alternatively, the special versions of the appropriate characters with the appropriate diacritics, could be suggested, upon long pressing on a letter.

Furthermore, a separate keyboard, perhaps, could be selected, that would be enhanced with the availability of these special diacritics available by long pressing on the keys where they could be used.

Thanks.